# Zxing change default orientation to horizontal

Tags: unity-game-engine, zxing

I'm using zxing on Unity3D and I noticed the default orientation is vertical. For my use case I need to scan barcode horizontally but I can't find how to rotate the default scan orientation. For now I can make it work using both `AutoRotate = true` and `TryHarder = true` but it slow down the process (since each image is processed in different orientations).
Any idea of how to do that? Thanks.

EDIT: trial working on vertical barcode only

```
//video feed from camera:
cameraFeed = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.GRAYSCALE);
if (cameraFeed == null)
{
return;
}

//reduce the area to scan
barcodeWidth = cameraFeed.BufferWidth;
barcodeHeight = (int)Mathf.Round(cameraFeed.BufferHeight / 2f);
barcodeLeft = 0;
barcodeTop = (int)Mathf.Round(barcodeHeight * 0.25f);

//create a new luminance with this settings
PlanarYUVLuminanceSource barcodeTexture = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(cameraFeed.Pixels, cameraFeed.BufferWidth, cameraFeed.BufferHeight, barcodeLeft, barcodeTop, barcodeWidth, barcodeHeight, false);

//rotate LuminanceSource by 90 degree
barcodeTexture2 = barcodeTexture.rotateCounterClockwise();

//read barcode
data = reader.Decode(barcodeTexture2);
```

EDIT2: another trial, working but too slow

```
Texture2D screenshot = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height/3);
screenshot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, (int)Mathf.Round(Screen.height / 3f), Screen.width, Screen.height / 3), 0, 0);
screenshot.Apply();
Color32[] color = screenshot.GetPixels32();
barcodeTexture3 = new Color32LuminanceSource(color, Screen.width, Screen.height / 3);
data = reader.Decode(barcodeTexture3);
```

Comment: Do you mean *screen* orientation? Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Resolution and Presentation -> Allowed Orientations

Comment: Thanks but no: my screen is in portrait mode (and should stay vertical) but I want to scan horizontal barcode. I think it's related to Zxing more than Unity.

Comment: Ah, *scanning barcodes.* That makes sense now.

Comment: You should rotate the captured image before you give it to ZXing. ZXing has no options to change the scanning orientation.
Alternativly you can initialize the barcode reader class with a custom luminance source handler if rotating the image counter clockwise works for you:
         var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader(null, bitmap =>
         {
            var result = new Color32LuminanceSource(bitmap);
            return result.rotateCounterClockwise();
         }, null);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought about this also and tried a similar code above (see *edit*) but it still read barcode vertically. Maybe I made a mistake (I'm not sure of how to use your sample)?

Comment: Scanning for barcodes is line oriented from "left" to the "right". So I'm not sure what you try to do. For better analysis I need a dump of the instance barcodeTexture.

Comment: I was trying to use the camera feed from Vuforia Plugin but I can't rotate it. I also tried to read the screen instead (see edit2), this time the reading does work horizontally but it's too slow on mobile (maybe I need to change some settings to process lighter images?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. By default the screen on mobile has a 90 rotation when using the portrait mode. Using `rotateCounterClockwise` rotate by 90 again so in none of these configuration I could read an horizontal barcode.
The solution I found is to use `rotateCounterClockwise` 3 time: 90(default)+3*90 = 0!

Thanks @Draco18s @Michael for the debug.

Answer (score 0):

I actually run across the exact same problem. I could come up with a solution that works for me. before getting the result via

`var result = barcodeReader.Decode(scannedPicture,CamTexture.width, CamTexture.height);`

I rotate the `scannedPicture` (which is a Color32[]) by 90 degrees and then providing it to `barcodeReader.Decode(...)`.
You will find a way to rotate a one dimensional array online. This will not only solve the problem with the orientation of the device but also give you the option to additionally check a rotated version of the currently scanned image, thus also scanning barcodes that are not aligned horizontally. This gave me an even more responsive experience with the scanner feature I built.